# Boost Graph Library cannot store references to other vertices?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I'm using BGL to build a graph storing bundled vertices where
one type of vertex stores a reference to the other vertex type. Both types are handled using std::variant:

```
struct simple_node_t {
    size_t enabled;
};

struct complex_node_t {
    bool foo1;
    size_t foo2;
    simple_node_t& control;
};

using vertex_t = std::variant<simple_node_t, complex_node_t>;

using netListGraph_t = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    vertex_t>;
```

Vertices of type complex_node_t are created and stored like this:

```
// Create node
complex_node_t cpx = {
    true,
    0xDEADBEEF,
    std::get<simple_node_t>(mGraph[desc_to_simple_vertex])
};

// Add complex_node_t to graph
vertex_t vtx(cpx);
auto vertex = boost::add_vertex(vtx, mGraph);
```

Now the problem:

```
auto pVal = std::get_if<complex_node_t>(&mGraph[vertex]);

assert(pVal->foo1 == true); //OK
assert(pVal->foo2 == 0xDEADBEEF); //OK
```

But accessing the reference fails (invalid object)!

```
**pVal->control.enabled -> GARBAGE**
```

Storing the data by value works - but storing by reference does not.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: My example is very reduced of course... that means the vertices I want to store via reference are much bigger.

**EDIT**

I now changed my code:

```
struct complex_node_t {
    bool foo1;
    size_t foo2;
    std::reference_wrapper<simple_node_t> control;
};
```

and try to access elements:

```
if (pVal->control.get().enabled) -> **STILL GARBAGE**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store a reference inside a class, it is no longer assignable nor default-constructible.

BGL Has the concept of a descriptor here, it's an abstraction of something like an array index, but independent of the graph representation. So you could use those.

Beware of invalidation rules though: depending on the graph model[1]. See

- [Should I use iterators or descriptors to keep a reference on an edge or vertex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350721/should-i-use-iterators-or-descriptors-to-keep-a-reference-on-an-edge-or-vertex)
- [BGL: storing vertex descriptors in a way that they won't invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723859/bgl-storing-vertex-descriptors-in-a-way-that-they-wont-invalidate)
- [In the Boost Graph Library, why does adding an edge invalidate Edge iterators (and other questions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881036/in-the-boost-graph-library-why-does-adding-an-edge-invalidate-edge-iterators-a)

PS. if you know your graph has reference stability for vertices you *could* do what you want replacing the reference with raw pointers or `std::reference_Wrapper<>`

---

[1] in the case of `adjacency_list<>` it depends on the vertex/edge container selector template arguments

#### Demo Code

This code demonstrates

- the mechanics of defining the graph (with self-referential descriptor types)
- how NOT to populate (see `// BUG`)
- how to safely populate/use the attributes instead.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0421f0c77161c4f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <variant>

using base_traits = boost::graph_traits<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> >;

struct simple_node_t {
    size_t enabled = 0;
};

struct complex_node_t {
    bool foo1 = false;
    size_t foo2 = 0;
    base_traits::vertex_descriptor control {};
};

using vertex_t = std::variant<simple_node_t, complex_node_t>;

using netListGraph_t = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    vertex_t>;

int main() {
    {
        netListGraph_t g;
        auto control = add_vertex(simple_node_t{12}, g);
        // BUG HERE:
        add_vertex(complex_node_t{ true, 42, control }, g); // whoops, might invalidate `control`
    }

    {
        netListGraph_t g(10);
        auto control = vertex(6, g);
        g[control] = simple_node_t{12};

        auto other   = vertex(4, g);
        g[other] = complex_node_t{ true, 42, control }; // fine

        // also fine:
        std::get<complex_node_t>(g[other]).control = control;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! once the graph is fully built it will be stable. So I think that using std::reference_wrapper<> would be the route to go!? Do you have a short example or some hints how I should do it in this case?

Comment: I edited the question to show how I tried to solve it. But it's not working... unfortunately. Any idea?

Comment: Be aware that you need to be setting the reference _after_ the graph became stable then. Added sample to my answer

Comment: Thanks again! Short question: Am I right you're now storing a vertex descriptor instead of reference or did I miss something? What I tried to achieve is storing a reference to an underlying object in a variant.

Comment: Indeed, since you said "once the graph is fully built it will be stable" I would go that way. Of course you _can_ use a raw pointer (reference wrappers only work if they're never uninitialized)

Comment: I wanted to avoid that additional indirection and store a reference. However this is where I fail. Don't know how to do that.

Comment: Got it: I missed the point the vecS get invalidated in my case.